# Count or Sum most sold product from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table with each product I sold, the database looks like this:

```
ID CODE QUANTITY PRICE PAID EARNINGS
```

As you can see its very basic, I sell a product and it gets saved there.

The problem now is my boss told me to show a page with the most sold products order by most sold to less sold.

```
In this case what I have to do is to count the QUANTITY field
```

OK here we go

```
<?php
$letsdoit = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `sales` SUM(quantity) AS `quantity` order by `quantity`");
while($show= mysqli_fetch_assoc($letsdoit )){
 ?>
```

Now we show the results of all sold products ordered by most sold (quantity) using the sum(quantity) and then we show the results like this

```
CODE <?php echo $mostrar['code'] ?> QUANTITY <?php echo $mostrar['quantity'] ?>
```

we close the WHILE

```
<?php }?>
```

The problem is, it is counting all products sold, tried another way and get

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

I never did a query so complicated like this
Can anyone give me a hand to see how it must be done?

Thanks a lot for any idea or help

Comment: Your query is invalid.

Comment: Try grouping products by code. Add group by (code) before order by part...

Comment: You forgot a "," before SUM: $letsdoit = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `sales`, SUM(quantity) AS `quantity` order by `quantity`");
while($show= mysqli_fetch_assoc($letsdoit )){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make your query as following

```
select code, count(*) as count from sold
group by code
order by count desc
```